How can we draw $x(t)=3\sin(t) \sin(3t),y(t)=3\cos(t) \cos(3t)$?
I tried to take multiple values for $t$ but this was a painful procedure. I wondered if there is any way to make to graph $(x,y)$ faster. However, every way I tried failed to work. For example, evaluating $x^2+y^2$ did not achieve anything.

Are you aware of product-to-sum trig identities? Sum/difference of cosines maybe easier to graph.

Rotating your coordinate system by $\frac\pi4$ and eliminating $t$ gives (in the new coordinates, say, $u, v$) $v$ as a quadratic expression in $u$, so the curves is an arc of a parabola.

It looks like $y-x=3 \cos(4t)$, but I don't know if this is useful.

"How can we draw..." : by using free online tools like Geogebra and Desmos !!!

For brevity, let $s = \sin(t)$ and $c = \cos(t)$.  Recall (or derive from DeMoivre's Formula) that:
$$\cos(3t) = c^3 - 3cs^2 = 4c^3 - 3c$$
$$\sin(3t) = 3c^2s - s^3 = 3s - 4s^3$$
So our parametric equations become:
$$x = 3s(3s - 4s^3)$$
$$y = 3c(4c^3 - 3c)$$
Or, expressing them as polynomials in terms of $s$ and $c$:
$$12s^4 - 9s^2 + x = 0$$
$$12c^4 - 9c^2 - y = 0$$
Using the quadratic formula,
$$s^2 = \frac{9 \pm \sqrt{81 - 48x}}{24}$$
$$c^2 = \frac{9 \pm \sqrt{81 + 48y}}{24}$$
Using the Pythagorean identity $s^2 + c^2 = 1$,
$$\frac{9 \pm \sqrt{81 - 48x}}{24} + \frac{9 \pm \sqrt{81 + 48y}}{24} = 1$$
From which straightforward algebraic manipulation (noting that the two $\pm$ signs are independent) gives the conic section:
$$2x^2 + 4xy + 2y^2 + 3x - 3y - 9 = 0$$

The eqaution of this conic section being $2(x+y)^2+3(x-y)^2-9=0$, it is a parabola.

Yes.
$$x(t)=3\dfrac{\cos(2t)-\cos(4t)}{2}$$
$$y(t)=3\dfrac{\cos(2t)+\cos(4t)}{2} $$
$$x+y=3\cos(2t)$$
$$x-y=-3\cos(4t)=-3(2\cos(2t)^2-1)$$
Can you link from here : $x+y$ and $x-y$ ?

@JOHN BOURAS If this answer suits to you fell free to accept it

Formula for $\sin (3x)$ and $\cos (3x):$
$$\sin(3x)=3\sin x-4\sin^3x, \cos(3x)=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$$
Thus, $$x(t)=9\sin^2t-12\sin^4t$$ $$\begin{align}y(t)=12\cos^4t-9\cos^2t&=3\cos^2(4\cos^2t-3)=3(1-\sin^2t)(1-4\sin^2t)\\&=12\sin^4t-15\sin^2t+3\end{align}$$
$x+y=-6\sin^2t$, $y-x=24\sin^4t-24\sin^2t+3$ and you can explore the relation between these two,
